# Goagent verify user through SMS. How to change the phone number setting of SMS?

Tags: google-app-engine

I just changed the my phone. and my phone number are also changed. Goagent verify user through SMS. If I can not change to new number, and I will not be able to log in outside web anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It's not only be verify by SMS but also by your E-mail.
So don't worry.